# Recursive Loop though all the controls on a form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I am trying to loop through all the controls in my form to allow for language localization of my application.

This is what I have.

```
    private void ChangeLanguage(string lang, ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (Control c in controls)
        {
            ChangeLanguage(lang, c.Controls);
            ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
        }
    }
```

It does not like how I try to derive the child controls from the parent.

Does anyone have any advice on how to accomplish my task?

Comment: What error are you getting? In what line? Compiler error or runtime error?

Comment: Why don't you use the localisation that's built into .NET? If you create a file `ResourceFile.FR-fr.resx` it will automatically pick it up when the locale is set to France.

Comment: Before changing anything with controls perhaps you need to write code that will check the type for example if a control is TextBox then do something..

Answer (score 0):

Ack. Don't do this. Check out Globalization and Localization. 
Basically you'll use

- the resource manager,
- Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
- Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.

Binding your control to the ResourceManager or populating values from the resource manager when the form renders is the correct way. The magic happens in a localized ResourceManager .resx.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx